# How I can make side menu bottom , buttons and content responsive?

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a side menu in my html code and I want to make it responsive. I want all of the side menu bottom, buttons and other contents to be responsive. But it is not happening. Below I have posted the code where you can see that if I drag my browser from bottom to upper, the window goes smaller, then buttons disappear. If you drag bottom to up then you can see buttons disappear. How can I solve this problem?

Here is the code I was trying so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
    theme: "minimal"
  });

  $('#dismiss').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
  });

  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
    $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
    $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
  });
});
```

```css
#sidebar {
  width: 425px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -425px;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sidebar.active {
  right: 0;
}

#dismiss {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #7386D5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#dismiss:hover {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7386D5;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
  position: relative;
}

ul.CTAs {
  padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
  background: #fff;
  color: #7386D5;
}

a.article,
a.article:hover {
  background: #6d7fcc !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.f-left {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.cart-img {
  position: relative;
}

p {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #999999;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.scrollbar {
  height: 500px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.force-overflow {
  min-height: 450px;
}

#style-5::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-5::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-5::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #0ae;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">

<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div id="dismiss">
      <i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <h3>Cart</h3>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <li>
        <div class="total-cart-pro">
          <!-- single-cart -->
          <div class="scrollbar" id="style-5">
            <div class="force-overflow">

              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="single-cart clearfix">
                <div class="cart-img f-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/phones/66417-xlarge/Samsung-Galaxy-S8-0.jpg" width="60px" />
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-info f-left">
                  <h6 class="text-capitalize">
                    <a href="#">Samsung S8 Smartphone</a>
                  </h6>
                  <p>
                    <span>Brand <strong>:</strong></span> Samsung
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Kogus <strong>:</strong></span> 1
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <span>Hind <strong>:</strong></span> 1000$
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
      <li><a href="#" class="download">Go Pay</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="article">Back to store</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


  <!-- Page Content Holder -->
  <div id="content">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
          <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                                <span>Open Sidebar</span>
                            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <h2>Collapsible Sidebar Using Bootstrap 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud </p>

    <div class="line"></div>

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore </p>

    <div class="line"></div>

    <h2>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore </p>

    <div class="line"></div>

    <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide more details about your question and what you have tried

Comment: @user9405863 I tryed #scrollbar height change to auto and 100% but it goes massive

Answer (score 0):

The side bar can be made responsive by using media query in CSS.
the below code is a example of  using media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .sidebar {
     width: 100%;
     overflow: scroll;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
   .sidebar {
     width: 80%;
     overflow: scroll;
  }
}
```

But remember that the media query must be placed below the default style.

for more information refer the link : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: one cannot forget to add this to the HTML code : <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Answer (score 0):

you have to work on the width and position of sidebar, and you have to use media queries to catch appropriate styles according to the screen size.

```
#sidebar {
  width: 100%;
  max-width:425px;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 999;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

and

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .sidebar {
     width: 100%;
     overflow: scroll;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   .sidebar {
     width: 80%;
     overflow: scroll;
  }
}
```

For the HTML part, make sure you add :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Please check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aw5ty84a/3/)

**EDIT**

For various screen sizes, you need to break your code with various media queries. For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  // your code for screen <=700 : applied to screens ranging from 700px to 641px
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  // your code for screen <=640 : applied to screens ranging from 640px to 561px
}
@media screen and (max-width: 560px) {
  // your code for screen <=560 : applied to screens ranging from 560px to 481px
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  // your code for screen <=480 : applied to screens ranging from 480px to 361px
}
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  // your code for screen <=360 : applied to screens ranging from 360px to 321px
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  // your code for screen <=320 : applied to screens ranging from 320px to 0px
}
```

Comment: I tryed it and its great, but if I uses iphone 4,5,6,7,8 media queries it is taking first querie and making it for all phones...

Comment: Because you need to customize the media queries according to the screen sizes you are supporting and for each of them, you want the menu to behave as. This was an example for the screen <=400px. So it will apply accordingly. See my edited answer.